# How to output used elements in a C++ Array

Tags: c++

I have a char array with say [100] elements, or reserved spaces. I use 5 of those spaces to place some random Name values. However, when I output I only want to output those 5 values and avoid outputting the other 95 empty spaces. I’ve tried using a for loop and while loop combined with an If statement to check if the array element at “i” was empty but it didn’t work. Please and thank you.

Comment: Implement a `count` variable to count the used elements.

Comment: @sjsam that’s not a bad idea let me try

Answer (score 0):

if you 'lost' the used size of the array all depend on the type of the element

- if you have a string and 'used' string are never empty you can check if the string is empty (the null character indicate the end of the string)
- if the element are float/double you can probably use Nan to detect an entry is not 'used'
- if the elements are integer you cannot have an 'empty' value, but may be the range of values for 'used' entries is reduced and you can check if the value is in the expected range
- ...

But you are in C++ why are you using array rather than for instance `std::vector` whose have a size ?

Comment: It is a char array set by default and i can’t switch it to vector.

Comment: @user11323842 and you cannot have both the array and its used size ? why the indication of the used size is lost ? you cannot use the null char as a terminator like in any string ?